# How to replace fully connected layers with conv1d in the output layer?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision

i'm using conv net for image classification, i built it from scratch and got some good results, false negative is low but false positive are high, m thinking of training the model again, this time with arbitrary input image shape, but fully connected layers need fixed image shape, therefore i want to replace them with Conv1d..
any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: FAUnet? Is it you?

Comment: Check here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/263349/how-to-convert-fully-connected-layer-into-convolutional-layer